# Send caller and callee to Meetme

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I want to send both caller and callee to meetme room.But its not working fine.This is my code:

```
[USER_CALL]
exten => s,1(start),Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=45)

exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/20000,,G(chat-room,add,1))


[chat-room]
exten => add,1,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=45)
exten => add,n,MeetMe(${CALLERID(num)},mt,unmute})
```

It show me follwing output:
    == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called 20000
    -- SIP/20000-0a9e8710 is ringing
    -- SIP/20000-0a9e8710 is ringing
    -- SIP/20000-0a9e8710 answered SIP/923028111415-b741da98
    -- Executing [add@chat-room:1] Set("SIP/923028111415-b741da98", "TIMEOUT(absolute)=45") in new stack
Channel will hangup at 2014-08-25 14:27:29.306 PKT.
    -- Executing [add@chat-room:2] MeetMe("SIP/923028111415-b741da98", "923028111415,mt,unmute}") in new stack
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/meetme.conf':   == Found
  == Spawn extension (chat-room, add, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/923028111415-b741da98'
    -- Executing [add@chat-room:2] MeetMe("SIP/20000-0a9e8710", "s,mt,unmute}") in new stack
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/meetme.conf':   == Found
  == Spawn extension (chat-room, add, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/20000-0a9e8710'

Please guide me through it.

Answer (score 0):

Seams you are triing to do n-way-call.

Check this for more info

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO

Please also not if you dooing it via G

```
G([[context^]exten^]priority): If the call is answered, transfer
the calling party to the specified <priority> and the called party to
the specified  <priority> **plus one.**
```

Hangup in your log most likly becuase of no dahdi module working on your system(meetme app require dahdi be availible) or becuase no room like you described availible(maybe need use d flag)

Comment: Thanks @arheops, it works. Juz want to ask one more thing what will be the DIALSTATUS if dial number is OFF.None of the following option fulfill my need:
BUSY,NOANSWER,CANCEL,CONGESTION, CHANUNAVAIL, DONTCALL, TORTURE,
INVALIDARGS, Do u have any idea which will be the status if Numver is power off. Many Thanks.

Comment: That depend of number type. For fxo/pstn will be busy. For sip/gsm will be congestion.